# Is there way to store the received json data from server in local or session storage in browser using python

Tags: python, asynchronous, browser, deployment, local-storage

```
localStorage = localStoragePy('app-namespace', 'local')
user = {
    'name':'Mathew',
}
def store_data():
    localStoragePy.setItem(localStorage,'user_id',user)

def get_store():
     values_1 =localStoragePy.getItem(localStorage,'ld_uid')
     if values_1 is None:
         print('It is there')

     return values_1
 
print(get_store())
```

I tried using pip install localStoragePy module. It is not working.